# Is $\tau_1$ is stronger than $\tau_2$?

Tags: general-topology

[image]let norms $||x||_1  = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |K_i|$ and $ ||x||_2= (\sum_{i=1}^{n}| K_i|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ induce  a  topology $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$  on $\mathbb{R}^n $ ,the  $n$ dimensional  euclidean space ,then

choose the correct option

$a)$ $\tau_1$ is weaker  than  $\tau_2$

$b)$ $\tau_1$ is stronger   than  $\tau_2$

$c)$ $\tau_1$ is equivalent    $\tau_2$

$d)$  $\tau_1$  and  $\tau_2$ are incomparable

My attempts  : I know that  $||x||_2   \le   ||x||_1 $  this implies  $\tau_1$ is stronger   than  $\tau_2$ so the  correct answer will be  option b)

is  it corrcet ??

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $\|x\|_2\leq \|x\|_1\leq \sqrt n \|x\|_2$ we see c) is correct.